# How to find an equation describing mass of sample over time, radioactive decay?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

If you have an initial mass of 50kg for a radioactive sample, which has a half-life of 5000 years, how would you go about finding an equation that describes the mass of the sample over time??

**My approach:**

N(t)=$N_0$$e^{-kt}$

N(5000)=50$e^{-5000k}$

I believe my approach to the problem is over simplified. Would the approach involve taking the derivative of $\frac{dN}{dt}$=$-kN$?

Comment: Using the derivative approach changes nothing, because it just gives you the same form of solution as you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really $N(t)=50\text{kg}\cdot 2^{-\frac{t}{5000\text{yr}}}$.

The formula $N(t)=N_0e^{-kt}$ is a correct formula where $k$ is the *decay rate*, but you are given *half-time*, and the decay rate is linked to the half-time via equation $t_{1/2}=\frac{\ln 2}{k}$ or $k=\frac{\ln 2}{t_{1/2}}$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Half-life).

Indeed, if you replace $k=\frac{\ln 2}{5000\text{yr}}$ you get:

$$N(t)=N_0e^{-\frac{\ln 2}{5000\text{yr}}t}=50\text{kg}\cdot 2^{-\frac{t}{5000\text{yr}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a **half** life. So at $t=5000$, the sample should have **halved**. You have the form of solution $N(t)=N_0 e^{-kt}$, and you know its mass at times $t=0$, and $t=5000$ - it is $50kg$ and $25kg$ respectively. Substituting this in gives two equations with 2 unknowns which can be solved to find $N_0$ and $k$.

Can you take it from here?